# Find Substring of A in B with n mistakes

Tags: python

I need to figure out if A is a substring of B while forgiving a certain number of errors (n). A and B are both strings and n is an integer. The biggest problem is my inner while loop. I'm not sure how to code it so that it outputs what I want. It should loop through B looking for a match of A with n mistakes. If A was "abcd" and B was "bdefabddghl" then the output should be that A was found at position 4 with 1 mistake.
This is the code I have right now. I just need to know how to code the inner while loop. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
def subsequence(A,B,n):
answer = -1             # assume worst case for there-exists type of loop
j = 0                   # index b
while j<=len(B)-len(A) and answer==-1:  # there exists j in b loop
    bx = j              # assume a is found in b starting at b[j]
    i = 0               # assume best case for a for-all type of loop
    axy = n             # accumulator for n
        while i<len(A) and bx==j and axy > 0:   # for all i in a
        if A[i] == B[j-i] and axy > 0:
            bx = j
            axy = n         # accumulator for n
        if A[i] != B[j-i] and axy > 0:
            axy -= 1
        i+=1
        # while i
    j+=1
# while j
end = "A best match with " + str(n-axy) + " errors was found starting at position " + str(bx)."
return end
print subsequence("abcd","bcjabddec",3)
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you considering insertions and deletions as well?

Comment: Some algorithms used for fuzzy string match are [ngrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram) and [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)

Comment: What do you mean by "mistake" in this context?

Comment: I think the question seeks to solve this exercise: http://www.cs.hofstra.edu/~cscccl/csc15p/dnalab.txt If that's right, it would indicate that insertions and deletions are indeed not allowed, only substitutions.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I'm trying to solve. I've spent a lot of time trying to figure it out and haven't gotten anywhere. I really just need a hint in the right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're working on this exercise, or something quite similar to it: http://www.cs.hofstra.edu/~cscccl/csc15p/dnalab.txt

I'm not sure that the starting example is particularly helpful. It's quite hard to understand and therefore quite hard to adapt in the way specified. I would make some recommendations on how to tackle such problems:

1. Break the problem down into smaller problems that are easier to solve.
2. Write code that tests each function gives the results you expect.
3. Use variable and function names that make it clear what each means, so that the code is easier to understand both for yourself and for those you show it to.

What you're trying to do is slide string A along string B and at each position test how good a match it is, remembering the best match that you find. An easy part of the problem to separate out is to measure how good a match you get at some specific alignment of the two strings.

Here's my suggestion for the general shape of a solution:

```
def string_distance(A, B, index_b):
    '''Count how many substitutions are required to
    change string A into the string beginning at
    index_b in string B.'''
    return 999 # FIXME

def subsequence(A, B, n):
    '''Search for the substring of B that is equal to
    A except for the minimal number of substitutions,
    and return a tuple of the index of that substring
    in B and the number of substitutions required,
    unless there is no such substring with n or fewer
    substitutions, in which case return the tuple of
    (-1, -1).'''
    answer_distance = -1
    answer_index = -1
    index = 0
    while index <= len(B) - len(A):
        substitutions_required = string_distance(A, B, index)
        # Does a match at this location need n or fewer substitutions?
        is_close_enough = False # FIXME
        # Is a match at this location better than the best match so far?
        is_better = False # FIXME
        if is_close_enough and is_better:
            answer_distance = substitutions_required
            answer_index = index
        index += 1
    return answer_index, answer_distance
```

And here's what some basic tests might look like:

```
def test_string_distance():
    test_data = [
        # a         b          index_b   expected
        ("ABC",    "ABCDEF",   0,        0),
        ("ABX",    "ABCDEF",   0,        1),
        ("XYZ",    "ABCDEF",   0,        3),
        ("XBC",    "ABCDEF",   0,        1),
        ("CEE",    "ABCDEF",   2,        1),
        ("DEF",    "ABCDEF",   3,        0),
        ("AAAAA",  "BBBBBBBB", 3,        5),
        ("BAAAA",  "BBBBBBBB", 3,        4),
        ("ABAAB",  "BBBBBBBB", 3,        3),
    ]
    for a, b, index_b, expected in test_data:
        result = string_distance(a, b, index_b)
        if result != expected:
            print "string_distance({}, {}, {}) was {} but should be {}".format(
                    a, b, index_b, result, expected)

def test_subsequence():
    test_data = [
        # A         B               n   expected
        ("AXY",    "AYAXXXAAYYAX",  3,  (2,1)),
        ("AXY",    "AYAXXXAAYYAX",  2,  (2,1)),
        ("AXY",    "AYAXXXAAYYAX",  1,  (2,1)),
        ("AXY",    "AYAXXXAAYYAX",  0,  (-1,-1)),
        ("XAAY",   "AYAXXXAAYYAX",  2,  (5,0)),
        ("XAAY",   "XXAXAAXAAY",    2,  (6,0)),
        ("ABCDEF", "ZZAABAXCDEEEF", 3,  (5,2)),
        ("ABCDEF", "ZZAABAXCDEEEF", 2,  (5,2)),
        ("ABCDEF", "ZZAABAXCDEEEF", 1,  (-1,-1)),
        ("ABCDEF", "ZZAABXBCDEEEF", 3,  (5,2)),
    ]
    for a, b, n, expected in test_data:
        result = subsequence(a, b, n)
        if result != expected:
            print "test_subsequence({}, {}, {}) was {} but should be {}".format(
                    a, b, n, result, expected)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_string_distance()
    test_subsequence()
```

First figure out an implementation of string_distance that will pass these tests. Then get subsequence working.

Comment: Thank you! This is really helpful :D I'll report back with what I come up with.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably take a look at `difflib.get_close_matches` function. It does almost the same thing. If you really want to implement it, it's much easier to do that by simply building a list of all subsequences of the same length and sort them by the number of matches.

```
def subsequence(a, b, n):

    sb = [(i, b[i:i+len(a)]) for i in xrange(len(b) - len(a) + 1)]

    def count_matches(s):
        return sum(int(x == y) for (x, y) in zip(a, s[1]))

    sb.sort(key=count_matches, reverse=True)

    best = sb[0]

    e = len(a) - count_matches(best)
    i = best[0]
    w = best[1]

    print 'A best match with %d errors was found starting at position %d' % (e, i)
```